# Node.js: cannot get json object on localhost

Tags: javascript, android, json, node.js, express

I have an android app that is going to send a json to my server where I will have a node.js express app. Meanwhile, I want to test it on my localhost.

On my android code I send the json to:

```
   new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://10.0.2.2:8080/ReceiveJson");
```

This code is triggered by a button and is working fine.

Then in my app.js file I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.get('/ReceiveJson', function(req, res) {

console.log(req.body);
res.send(req.body);
res.json(req.body);
res.send("ok");
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

In my terminal I run node app.js and I get just the answer "Express server is listening on port 8080". Nothing else.

When I go to my browser and put

```
http://localhost:8080/ReceiveJson
```

I get "{}" as an answer.
In my terminal I get the same answer.

What do I have to do to receive the json?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are responding with the req.body:

```
 res.send(req.body);
```

The code below it never gets called because you have already responded:

```
res.json(req.body);
res.send("ok");
```

Because you are using a web browser, there is nothing being sent in the body because it is a get request and there will be nothing in the body for a get request, therefore you get an empty json object, hence {}.

If you change your code to:

```
app.get('/ReceiveJson', function(req, res) {
    res.send("ok");
});
```

Then when you browse there in your browser you will get the response 'ok'

If you are looking to post or put to your express server then you need to use either app.post or app.put.  I noticed that you are trying to send JSON with an Android device for an app you have already written.  I would highly recommend using Fiddler or something to test with, just make sure that when you send JSON to your express app you are using the header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

EDIT:

Your JSON might not be working because you aren't using the body parser.  Try inserting this in your code before app.listen

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
})
```

Comment: Hi. It is working now, I am getting the result ok on my terminal. But I still receiving an empty json with the code console.log(req.body). On the client side (android) I am getting that the json was perfectly sent. I am still not sure what went wrong. Thanks for your help

Comment: Upvote and mark correct?  I added some code to help you with your body json

Comment: Now I am facing this other problem: I created a variable: var globalId = 0; Than, I transform this globalId to 1 and in console it shows to 1. After I make client.set("id", globalId). When I do client.get("id", function(err, res { console.log(res); }); I get the value is 0 and not 1 as a transformed and debugged before. Why I can not set a value from a local variable that was changed inside code before going to redis?